# Invalid keyword argument for open function in csv pythons

Tags: python, csv, beautifulsoup

I am getting an error when m add skiprows using open function, as well as well my loop is good.
urls is Staring from 5column 2nd row, how to scrape it

```
import csv

f = open('Click_List.csv', 'r',skiprows=1)
reader = csv.reader(f)
links = []

for row in reader:
    links.append(row)
    for link in links:
        response = requests.get(link[5])
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
        title = print(soup.find('pre')) `
```

Comment: Just call `next(reader)` before your for loop if you want to skip the first row.

Comment: what is the exact error you're getting? Also, I'm not quite following the 2 for loops. You iterate through reader, and then add these to links, and then iterate through links. If I read this correctly, the following would happen if `reader == [link1, link2, link3]`: first reader loop: `links == [link1]`, second reader loop: `links == [link1, link2]`, so you would loop through link1 twice in the links loop. Third reader loop you would loop through link1 three times in the links loop, and twice for link2, etc

Comment: *skiprows* is used with pandas

Comment: python open https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open has no skiprows arguement, you might be looking at pandas read_csv

Answer (score 0):

I have done that `next(reader)`
part now its showing different error. what to do.

````
import csv

reader = csv.reader(df)
links = []

next(reader)

for row in reader:
    links.append(row)
    for link in links:
        response = requests.get(link[5])
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
        title = print(soup.find('pre'))```


<ipython-input-76-7eeb2c5080d1> in <module>
      8     links.append(row)
      9     for link in links:
---> 10         response = requests.get(link[5])
     11         soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
     12         title = print(soup.find('pre'))

IndexError: list index out of range
````